# Biblatex Package Problem

Tags: biblatex

i need your help, cause  I need to use the bibliography.
I use Bibtex for my Literature and tried to implement it info my study, but it don't work.

Could anybody help me with it?
The failure is: incompatible Package ucs.

```
%-------------------
%Beginn des Kopfbereiches
%-------------------

\documentclass[liststotoc,bibtotoc]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{paralist}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{color} % Farben
\definecolor{codegray}{gray}{.95}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,.6}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{.6,0,0}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,.6,0}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{.98,0,0}
\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, frame=single, backgroundcolor=\color{codegray},
  breaklines, showstringspaces=false, commentstyle=\itshape\color{darkgreen},
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{darkblue}, stringstyle=\color{darkred},
  xleftmargin=0.5cm}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

%Literaturverzeichnis
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Bib}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}


%\usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\usepackage{setspace}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

%\setlength{\parskip}{1.0em}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=30mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry} 

\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark\ }}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}


%-------------------
%Ende des Kopfbereiches
%-------------------


%-------------------
%Hier beginnt der Text der Hausarbeit
%-------------------
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} 

%Beginn der Titelseite
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{small}
\vfill {Universität Hamburg\\ 
Fachbereich Informatik\\ 
EvS\\ 
Sommersemester 2014}
\end{small}

\begin{center}
\vfill {\textsf{
\bigskip
\begin{Large}
\textbf{SOAR  \\  Plattform und Einsatz- und Anwendungsgebiete} \\
\end{Large}
}}


\begin{large}
\vfill {\textsf{Seminararbeit \\}

}
\end{large}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{large}
\begin{onehalfspace}



\end{onehalfspace}
\end{large}
\end{center}

\begin{small}
\vfill {
Bearbeitet von: Christin 
Eingereicht am: 07. Dezember 2014\\}
\end{small}

\end{titlepage}
%Ende der Titelseite

\tableofcontents 

\newpage 
\listoffigures
\newpage 
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%Beginn einer neuen Seite
\clearpage

\onehalfspacing

\pagestyle{plain}

\section{Einleitung}

\subsection{Motivation}

In dieser Seminararbeit ...


\newpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you put four spaces before your code, it is displayed in a code box (short cut : mark the code, press `ctrl+k` on a WindowsPC, or choose `{}` from the menu). Try changing the line `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. `utf8x` loads `ucs` which is incompatible with most other packages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Replace `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. If you really need the capacities of  utf8x, compile with `Xe/LuaLaTeX`.

Comment: OK, Thanks. Latexian is compiling.
But i can't see my Bibliography.. :(

Comment: Did you execute the `pdflatex`-`bibtex`-`pdflatex`-`pdflatex` cycle?

Comment: @Bernard Latexian doesn't really give you any options over the build process

Comment: A few hints: [minimale Vorlage vs. maximale Probleme](http://www.komascript.de/node/1691) und [Kann ich Schriftgrößenumschaltungen auch als Umgebungen verwenden?](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/1852/kann-ich-schriftgroenumschaltungen-auch-als-umgebungen-verwenden). You should use either indented paragraphs or use a short vertical space ([Wie erhalte ich eine Leerzeile zwischen Absätzen?](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/113/wie-erhalte-ich-eine-leerzeile-zwischen-absatzen)).